# How can I find the parameters for a Gaussian exponential waveform?

Tags: exponential-function, parameter-estimation

I have a double Gaussian shaped waveform

```
`eta = H1 exp(-C1(x-X1)^2)-H2 exp(-C2(x-X2)^2`
```

where `x` is given and `H1`, `H2`, `C1`, `C2`, `X1`, `X2` are the parameters. The parameters are known. I want to produce a second waveform using `eta` called `eta_b`. 
`Eta_b` is described by the same mathematical expression where max(eta) = `eta(k)` and `max(eta_b) = eta_b(k)` and `eta(k) = eta_b(k)` and as `max(eta_b)` and `eta(1), eta(2),...,eta(k) = eta_b(1), eta_b(2),...,eta_b(k)`. The waveform from `eta_b(k),eta_b(k+1),...,eta_b(n)` should be `> eta(k), eta(k+1),...,eta(n)`.

Here is the actual output of `eta`:

[image]

I want to maintain the eta(max), eta(min), their position and wavefront steepness but the back part should be wider.

How can I find the parameters `H1, H2, C1, C2, X1, X2` for `eta_b`?

Thanks for helping me out!